# Private Key string not passing when store in key vault or in configuration settings deployed to azure function

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I have a private key string that if within my local.settings.json works fine (in any of the formats I explain below).

However, the same string copied and pasted into a secret on keyvault (or set in a app functions configuration) errors out.

If the string contains the "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n....\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n" part it states that the string needs to start and end with the tags that are already included.

If I change the secret or config to be only the inner string between "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n....\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n" and I form the full private key in code it states a base64 format error when passing through to the ServiceAccountCredential function for the Google SDK (I am working with Google Analytics).

Does some formatting occur based on the configuration type and if so is there a way around it?

would it be to store the file?

Regards
Mark

Comment: Think i may have figured it out.

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: @AnandaPrasadBandaru the answer that is below this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string in question was of a number of characters and there were \n in there a number of times. When reading from the local.settings.json it formatted the string and put the newlines in where it needed.

However, when the string was placed in keyvault or in the configuration area of the app function it did not parse the string in the same manor and it kept the \n within the string and therefore made the string invalid.

I just replace \n in the string with environment.newline.

Hope this saves someone the time I spent wasting on something that was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

I stripped out the "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" and "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----" part out fo the key and stored just the key value in the config. When doing that is seems like the newline character (Hex 0A) gets converted to a space (Hex 20).

Then when I need the key, I just do this:

```
const MY_PRIVATE_KEY =`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
${process.env["PRIVATE_KEY"].replace(/\x20/g,'\x0A')}
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`
```

Note the way I have formatted the above, there is a newline character added at the beginning and the end of the key.